# Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}$ be a rational-valued function of the rational variable $x$. Find the domain and range.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}$ be a rational-valued function of the rational variable $x$. Then find the domain and range of the function.

I tried to solve this problem but could not reach the answer. Since $x,f(x)\in \Bbb{Q}$, I let $f(x)=p\in \Bbb{Q}$.

$$p=\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}\Rightarrow p^2=x^2+3x+4\Rightarrow x^2+3x+4-p^2=0$$

Since $x$ is a rational number,so the discriminant of the quadratic equation is perfect square and $\geq0$.

$$9-4(4-p^2)\geq0\Rightarrow 4p^2-7\geq0$$

But I am not getting the answer which is

domain $f$: 
$$\left\{ {x~|~x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},~p\ne\frac{3}{2}},~p\in \Bbb{Q}\right\}$$

range $f$:
$$\left\{ {y~|~y=\frac{p^2-3p+4}{2p-3},~p\ne\frac{3}{2}},~p\in \Bbb{Q}\right\}$$

Please help me.

Comment: but i'm getting $$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 p^2-7}-3\right)$$ or $$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 p^2-7}-3\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s=\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}$. Then,
$$s^2=x^2+3x+4\Rightarrow x^2+3x+4-s^2=0.$$
Since the discriminant has to be the square of a rational number, we have
$$3^2-4\cdot 1\cdot (4-s^2)=t^2,\quad\text{i.e.}\quad 4s^2-7=t^2$$
for some $t\in\mathbb Q$.

So, we want $s,t\in\mathbb Q$ where $s\gt 0$ such that 
$$(2s)^2-t^2=7.$$

Now let us consider a hyperbola $x^2-y^2=7$. We want every rational $x\gt 0$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

First of all, $(x,y)=(-4,3)$ is on the hyperbola. So, for $u\in\mathbb Q$, by Vieta's formulas, the $x$ coordinate $\alpha$ of the intersection point other than $(-4,3)$ of the hyperbola with a line  $y-3=u(x-(-4))$ is also rational :

$$x^2-(ux+4u+3)^2=7$$$$(1-u^2)x^2+(-8u^2-6u)x-16u^2-24u-16=0$$
$$-4+\alpha=-\frac{-8u^2-6u}{1-u^2}\Rightarrow \alpha=\frac{4u^2+6u+4}{1-u^2}$$
In order for this to be positive, we need to have $-1\lt u\lt 1$.

On the other hand, if the intersection point of the hyperbola with the line passing through $(-4,3)$ is a rational point, then the slope of the line is also rational.

Thus, we know that every rational $x\gt 0$ such that $x^2-y^2=7$ where $y\in\mathbb Q$ can be written as
$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4u^2+6u+4}{1-u^2},-1\lt u\lt 1,u\in\mathbb Q\right\}.$$

It follows from $s=\frac x2$ that **the range of $f$** is
$$\left\{y\mid y=\frac{2u^2+3u+2}{1-u^2},-1\lt u\lt 1,u\in\mathbb Q\right\},$$
i.e.
$$\left\{y\mid y=\frac{p^2-3p+4}{2p-3},\color{red}{p\gt\frac 32},p\in\mathbb Q\right\}.$$

Here, I set $u=\frac{2-p}{p-1}=-1+\frac{1}{p-1}$. Note here that $p$ has to be larger than $\frac 32$ because $y$ has to be positive.

Then, from $x^2+3x+4-y^2=0$, 
$$x=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-4\left(4-\left(\frac{p^2-3p+4}{2p-3}\right)^2\right)}}{2}=\frac{-3\pm\frac{2p^2-6p+1}{2p-3}}{2}=\frac{p^2-6p+5}{2p-3},\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3}$$

So, **the domain of $f$** is 
$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{p^2-6p+5}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}\cup\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}.$$

By the way, we have
$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{p^2-6p+5}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}=\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\color{red}{\lt}\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}$$
because $\frac{\color{blue}{(3-p)}^2-6\color{blue}{(3-p)}+5}{2\color{blue}{(3-p)}-3}=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3}$.

It follows from this that **the domain of $f$** is
$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{p^2-6p+5}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}\cup\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\},$$i.e.
$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\lt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}\cup\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\gt\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\},$$
i.e.$$\left\{x\mid x=\frac{4-p^2}{2p-3},p\not=\frac 32,p\in\mathbb Q\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that
$$\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}=y\tag{1}$$
with rational $x$, $y$.  Since $x^2+3x+4>0$ for real $x$ we  have $y>0$. The rational numbers
$$u:={2x\over y},\qquad v:={2\over y}$$
then satisfy
$$u^2+3uv+4v^2={4x^2+12x+16\over y^2}=4\ ,$$
whence are rational points on the ellipse ${\cal E}: \ u^2+3uv+4v^2=4$. Conversely: Any  rational point $(u,v)\in{\cal E}$ with $v>0$ determines a solution of $(1)$ via $$x:={u\over v},\quad \>y:={2\over v}\ .\tag{2}$$ 
In order to find the rational points on ${\cal E}$ we note that $P:=(0,1)$ is such a point. If $W:=(u,v)$ is another rational point on ${\cal E}$ then the line $P\vee W$ has rational slope $m$. We therefore intersect the line $v= 1+m u$  through $P\in{\cal E}$ a second time with ${\cal E}$ and obtain the point
$$(u,v)=\left(-{3+8m\over 1+3m+4m^2}, \>{1-4m^2\over 1+3m+4m^2}\right)\in{\cal E}\cap{\mathbb Q}^2\ ,$$
and all rational points on ${\cal E}$ apart from $(0,-1)$ are obtained in this way. As we want $v>0$ we have to restrict $m$ to $-{1\over2}<m<{1\over2}$. In this way we obtain from $(2)$ the following parametrization of the rational solutions of $(1)$:
$$x=-{3+8m\over 1-4m^2}\ ,\quad y={2(1+3m+4m^2)\over 1-4m^2}\qquad\left(m\in\ \bigl]-{1\over2},{1\over2}\bigr[\ \cap{\mathbb Q}\right)\ .\tag{3}$$
The domain of the function $f$ in question is then the set of $x$ generated by $(3)$, and the range of $f$ is the set of $y$ generated by $(3)$. Looking at the corresponding graphs one sees that the domain is unbounded below and above, while  the range is bounded below by ${\sqrt{7}\over2}$, and unbounded above.

Answer (score 0):

As f(x) is a real valued function the domain and range both should be real.
$f(x)=\sqrt{ (x^2 + 3x + 4) }\\
x^2 + 3x + 4 ≥ 0 $for f to be real \ 
If we graph this function it is always positive as it's lowest point$ (\frac{-3}{2},\frac{7}{4}) $is positive.
The lowest point is calculated by differntiating the function and setting it equal to zero. It is the  point where the function turns upwards.
Therefore in$ f(x) x\epsilon R $
For range of $f(x)$
Let $\\f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)} where g(x)=x^2 + 3x + 4\\
$
.Minimum value of $f(x)$ will be (minimum value of g(x))$^{({\frac{1}{2}})}$
$\\f(x)≥\sqrt{\frac{7}{4}}\\
=> f(x)≥\frac{\sqrt7}{2}\\$
Maximum value of f(x)=(maximum value of g(x))$^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
f(x)≤\sqrt∞\\
f(x)<∞. \\\\\\$
$f(x)\epsilon[\frac{\sqrt7}{2},∞)$ where $x\epsilon R$

Comment: I did it for a real valued function